# Azure App Service could not connect to Azure SQL database on same tenant

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I am hit with a new issue that began yesterday. I have an Azure subscription and earlier, my Azure SQL database (PaaS) allowed me to connect any resources within Azure subscription without whitelisting the IP address; only public networks needed to be whitelisted to Azure SQL database.

However, from today I am being prompted by other services like Azure App Services, Azure Logic Apps...etc that its unable to connect to Azure SQL database.

How can I allow resources within Azure Subscription to connect to Azure SQL database without whitelisting their outgoing IP addresses?

**Update**

Azure SQL DB > Networking > Exceptions > Allow Azure Services and resources to access this server was set to `false`

Comment: Can you provide more information regarding the issue?

Comment: @Jahnavi Thanks for reaching Out. It was able to resolve the Issue. For some reason, Azure SQL DB's Allow Azure Services and resources to access this Server was unchecked. I checked it back and it seems to work.

Comment: if issue resolved post the answer to help other community members facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems for some reason, the **Allow Azure Services and resources to access this server** feature of Azure SQL DB was set to `false`; if not un-checked. Checking it sought things.

To Access, Go to Azure > Azure SQL DataBase > Set Server Firewall Or Go to Azure > Azure SQL Server >  Networking and simply uncheck "Allow Azure Services and resources to access this server" shown below.

[image]

Comment: By checking that option, you are allowing any and all Azure services to bypass your firewall which is violating Azure best practices.  It'll show up on security scan.  In other words you are removing your firewall so that's why it solved your access problem.  Only secure solution I know of is - create private endpoint between consumer and provider so you don't need to check that "Allow..." option.